# TypeScript and jQuery scope error - code 1 while compiling

Tags: jquery, scope, typescript

Does anyone know why the hell i can't use jQuery in my TypeScript code (tho it looks like noone else doesn't have that problem).

I've made a new TypeScript project in VS2012, included the jquery.d.ts, added a script tag pointing to jquery cdn in the main html file, and in the main app.ts file i've added "

```
///  <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

at the top of the file and underneath a simple line  "$("something").hide();". The intellisense worked fine, tho when I try to compile it I get an error with code 1. I checked it in the command window and it said "The name '$' does not exist in the current scope".

Does anyone know whats going on? Generally I have a very hard time splitting my code to different files, I had to write the whole app in one file. I tried to use modules, import and export but everything ends up in a scope error thrown by the compiler :/

Please save me

EDIT @Sohnee
Its a default Typescript project from VS:

Structure:

```
app.css
app.ts
  --app.js
default.htm
jquery.d.ts
```

Modified files:

1) app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

$("body").hide();
```

2) default.htm

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference looks incorrect.

```
/// <_reference path="jquery.d.ts" />"
```

Should be

```
/// <reference path="./jquery.d.ts" />
```

The only way I can recreate this issue is by making the reference path invalid.

For example, I get the same error as you in these situations:

Missing slash:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts">
```

Missing quote (or missing both quotes):

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts />
```

Invalid path:

No code example for this one, but if you have `jquery.d.ts` in a different folder to your script, the path needs to be relative.

Works fine:

```
/// <reference path="./jquery.d.ts" />
```

Comment: i couldnt write it that way - XSS protection on stackoverflow? how did you do it?

Comment: nvm got it :P anyway thats not the case

Comment: If you precede the code block with 4 spaces it normally allows anything in the code block. What was the issue in the end?

Comment: Damn we got on a wrong track :D I meant "i got it" with the code block issue. The error thing is still not resolved.

Comment: I have tested a ton of scenarios and listed the ones that can cause a problem in the answer. Also, check the contents of `jquery.d.ts` just to ensure that right at the bottom it has `declare var $: JQueryStatic`.

Comment: I ve checked the reference statement a couple times (including relative paths) and nothing works. But i also found out that tho the error appears in the VS output, the app works just find like it was compiled without errors. Weird but at least it works. I wonder if it will also work with my seperate modules, where i had the sam problem. Anyways big thanks for the great effort :)

Answer (score 0):

How does the `jquery.d.ts` looks like?

it should be something like

```
interface JQuery {
hide();
}
interface JQueryStatic {
(query: string): JQuery; 
(ready: () => any): any;
}
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

now add it as a dependency inside the `app.ts` like (not a big fan of putting periods in the filenames so im going to call it custom.ts

```
/// <reference path="custom.ts" />
$(function(){$("body").hide();});
```

now build the solution if you have the [web essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) installed it wil generate the `custom.js` and `app.js` for you

now run the project, hopefully you'll not see a thing because the `body` will be hidden.

for more information Read the [TypeScript Lang Specs](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:2p0yN7PhPuIJ%3awww.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%2520Language%2520Specification.pdf%20&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgyAZ9Cr-xQpHYLXj629LoqiwvHYV4CZnhdgQxyN9_N61B8IssGYj_-iMjraphZR8OVkPdazw1WHegAPArLZJZ1FQcnFei_R6Z-1sIShlgpyd1v0n0l8NUEsrjMN7Yhidd4gZM3&sig=AHIEtbRk0970XLtvT1v6Jj6a9xc8yV7aSg)